# Using prerender.io for SEO on my AngularJS app - Dynamic and static web pages

Tags: seo, google, web-crawlers, sitemap

I have a website that was built with AngularJS. I want the website to be crawled by search engines (with the dynamic content).

I've tried to use Google services to do the crawl (from a sitemap.xml file) but I could not manage to make it work. (the sitemap was reloaded good - and he did read all the URL's in file, but every time I searched for a specific URL from the website - which appeared in the sitemap file, it showed a message that the file is not indexed and not crawled)

My last hope was prerender.io - which supposed to help to crawl after dynamic pages - I followed the documentation - installed it in my node app with the token I got, loaded the sitemap.xml file - and still, I don't see any cached pages. I would glad to get some help because I can't find any help with this problem on the internet. If you have any other suggestions for crawling dynamic websites - you're welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!

Comment: Google is not real-time. How long are you waiting? It can take weeks or even months before Google will fetch and index any particular page.

Comment: AngularJS and SPAs are SEO suicide despite what Google says.

Comment: @closetnoc thank you. iv'e waited a few weeks and still nothing indexed. do you got any suggestion?

Comment: @JohnConde any other suggestion?...